# Unity 3D Не сохраняется сцена

Tags: unity3d

Редактирую сцену сохраняю, перехожу на другую, потом обратно на изначальную сцену и все изменения которые я вносил пропадают.
Изначально нужная сцена была скопирована с другой. Также в сцене используются клоны объектов с другой сцены взятые с запущенной игры (тоесть запускаю сцену в игровой режим, сравниться n количество объектов я их беру и копирую на другую сцену).
И чтобы я не делал на сцене все сбрасывается. Не пойму в чем причина

Answer (score 1):

Иногда тоже такое бывает из-за забывчивости. При копировании сцены она создается просто как... файл. А вам нужно добавить сцену в сам движок. Для этого нажмите на нужную сцену, перейдите File->BuildSettings. И нажмите там кнопку AddOpenScenes. Это добавит и сохранит вашу сцену в движок, чтобы потом вы смогли игру собственно Build - скомпилировать. После того, как вы нажали эту кнопку, то при дальнейшем изменении на сцене и переходе на другую сцену будет выскакивать сообщение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Надо нажать Save, чтобы сохранить сцену. При создании сцены любым образом (копирование или File->New Scene), вы должны сохранить ее в BuildSettings.

Если мой ответ помог вам, пожалуйста, нажмите галочку и чуть выше стрелочку вверх. Это даст другим пользователям понять, что вопрос решен. А если остались вопросы - задавайте, отвечу.

Comment: Мне помогла простая перезагрузка движка

Comment: При перезагрузке сохраненные сцены добавляются автоматически. Но затем перезагружать движок если можно добавить сцену в движок вручную в пару кликов?